# CheckMicrosoftNetNativeCompilerCompatibility

Tags: xamarin.forms

> The target CheckMicrosoftNetNativeCompilerCompatibility does not exist in the project.

I am getting the above issue in Xamarin.uwp project in Xamarin.forms. I tried with restarting the VisualStudio and restarted System also. Still, I am getting the same issue. I tried in google also. But,there is no solution for this issue.

Can anyone please provide the solution for the above issue as soon as possible?

Thank You.

Comment: Could you show more detail about target version of  your uwp client project and current installed window 10 SDK in your computer?

Comment: Target Version is: Windows 10(10.0;Build  10240) and Min Version is:Windows 10(10.0;Build  10240)

Comment: Only One the above Target version is there..

Comment: Please try to  update the version of Windows 10 SDK  to Build 14393.

Comment: I had this error display when I accidentally used an older version of Visual Studio than the version the project was created in.

Comment: Yeah, For this, we need to update the Windows SDK , But I am not able to update that also.